# SQL group by throws error

Tags: sql

I want to display the name of the employee having maximum CTC in a a particular domain.

```
select Domain, max(CTC) from Employee group by Domain
```

This will display the Domain and maximum CTC for that particular domain.

but if I use

```
select Domain,empname, max(CTC) from Employee group by Domain
```

then its displaying error which is obvious 
So to coorect it if I modify it

```
select Domain,empname, max(CTC) from Employee group by Domain,empname
```

which gives a wrong output

but I need to display the employee name along with Domain and maximum CTC.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does one domain have more than one employee? For example, if one domain has 5 employees, is the desired output is 5 rows containing the name of each employee, domain and MAX(CTC)?

Comment: one domain contains more than 1 employee.And desired output for your example will be 1 or more rows containing employee(s) with max CTC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select m.Domain, e.empname, m.max_CTC 
from Employee e
join (select Domain, max(CTC) max_CTC from Employee group by Domain) m
on e.Domain = m.Domain
and e.CTC = m.max_CTC
```

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6cffe/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT E.Domain,E.empname,E.CTC FROM
Employee E JOIN
(select Domain,max(CTC) MaxCTC from Employee group by Domain) T
ON E.Domain = T.Domain AND E.CTC = T.MaxCTC
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6cffe/4)**

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

When you use an aggregate function, you need to group by all other column names in the select query.

**Solution:**

You have to use a join.

Try this:

```
SELECT E2.Domain,E1.empname,E2.MaxVal as Max
FROM Employee E1 INNER JOIN
(SELECT Domain,MAX(CTC) as MaxVal FROM Employee GROUP BY Domain) E2 
ON E1.Domain=E2.Domain
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Try This code this is simple;

```
select MAX(Domain),empname, max(CTC) from Employee group by empname
```